# Drupal 6 can I truncate the batch table in the db

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, drupal-6, batch-file

My batch table has become huge and is slowing down my site. No batch seems to be running.
Can I truncate the table safely?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can safely truncate that table if there are no batch processes running.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you did. My batch table was huge (almost 40 MiB). I went through the records in the database and I have found that the only thing that is stored in the database are settings of the batch task. I truncated the table manually without any noticable problem. I am not a Drupal DB guru but that solved my problem and none issue occured.

Maybe will someone advice othewise?

```
TRUNCATE `batch` ;
```